# Cordova + jquery mobile + jquery white screen of death on gingerbread

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, android-2.3-gingerbread

I've written an app in cordova 4.0 with jquery mobile & jquery, and when I try to run the app on Galaxy 2 with android 2.3.5 (gingerbread) all I get is white screen without any error or anything going on.

note: I capture any exceptions from javascript and alert them, so if there was an exception I should have seen a message. but there's nothing.

any idea why? does Cordova suppose to work properly on android 2.x? I found mix opinions on that subject...

thanks!

EDIT: adding the source code. note that I have js that wrap cordova so everything under utils.* is a wrapper layer for cordova. this is index.html, the first page that should be loaded. another thing I want to say is that I added a code to catch and alert any exceptions (window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber)...) and alert them, and it usually work but in this case I see no alert.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

part of pages we load does not work.
-->

```
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" /> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">   

    <!-- My extensions to jquery-mobile css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my-jquerymobile-extend.css" />

    <!-- all basic css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/msgbox.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/intro.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/splash.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/result_page.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/intlTelInput.css" />
    <title>SeekWhale</title>

    <!-- include cordova and jquery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="telephonenumber.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/custom_loading_gif.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-ui-draggable.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include utils -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/config.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/flags.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/ajax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/visuals.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/device.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/contacts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/events.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/navigation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/phone_numbers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/prompt.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/forms.js"></script>

    <!-- Replace UI language with chosen language -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/languages/dictionary.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/languages/hebrew.js"></script>

    <!-- function to init pages -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/init_page.js"></script>  

</head>

<body data-role="page">

    <img class="splash" src="img/bg-entry.png"></img>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // set language
        ui_dictionary.set_dictionary_words();

        // called when cordova is ready to run page init script
        function InitApp()
        {
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                utils.prompt.log("app started!");
                var effect = utils.navigation.transition.slidedown;

                // if should skip directly to main
                if (utils.flags.skip_to_main)
                {
                    utils.prompt.log("skip to main page");
                    utils.navigation.load_page(utils.config.get_last_page(), effect);
                }
                // if require first setup open the first setup page:
                else if (utils.config.get_successfully_registered() == false)
                {
                    utils.prompt.log("load register");
                    utils.navigation.load_page("register.html", effect);
                }
                // if registered but not confirmed, go to confirm page
                else if (utils.config.get_is_device_confirmed() == false)
                {
                    utils.prompt.log("load confirm page");
                    utils.navigation.load_page("confirm.html", effect);
                }
                // if all goes well, open the main page!
                else
                {
                    utils.prompt.log("load main page");
                    utils.navigation.load_page("main.html", effect);
                }
            }, 1);
        }
        utils.events.on_device_ready(InitApp);

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: show your code here.

Comment: Did you test your code on a browser or another device/emulator? If there were any compatibility issues between Cordova and Android 2.x, you'd be stopped from installing the app at the first place. It must be some error in syntax which is causing this. Check the console logs in the browser/ADB or like Dato said above, show us the code which you're running.

Comment: hello Keval, Dato, I added the source code for index.html, basically it just include all javascripts and load the next page. nothing much. the apps works on several android devices, but they all have Jelly Bean or higher. I never tried it in web. PS. the last time I got this white screen of death (simply white screen with nothing happening) was when I had a problem with one of the plugins, and reinstalling them fixed it. currently I have only Contacts plugin and com.simonmacdonald.telephonenumber plugin (I temporarily disabled all the rest)

Comment: Got any solution for this? I'm facing this combo issue in iOS 9 beta version. Jqm 1.4.0 & jQ 2.0.1

Comment: @Brune nope, just dropped gingerbread support. but there might be a solution I just didn't look for very long.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

this one should be the first js to be loaded. put all other js files after it.